# Stack level too deep or unknown attribute: password_confirmation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I'm working on a web app that has users model. You either sign up or try the app and be a 'guest'. I had the sign up functionality working well until I added the guest option. I based on Railscast to do this (http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record) and that's when I ran into troubles

Here is my **user model** code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_many :bookings
  has_one :account, dependent: :destroy

  # before_save :downcase_email, allow_nil: true
  before_save :create_remember_token
  validates_presence_of :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, unless: :guest?
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, case_sensitive: false , allow_blank: true   
  validates :name, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, unless: :guest?
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 },  unless: :guest?

  def downcase_email
    { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  end

  # has_secure_password
  # override has_secure_password to customize validation until Rails 4.
  require 'bcrypt'
  attr_reader :password, :password_confirmation
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword::InstanceMethodsOnActivation

  ##def to_param
  ##  "#{id}.#{name.parameterize}"
  ##end

  def self.new_guest
   new { |u| u.guest = true }
  end

  def name
    guest ? "Guest" : name
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

and here is my **User Controller** code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = params[:user] ? User.new(params[:user]) : User.new_guest
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      @user.create_account.accountPlan = "Free"
      ##flash[:success] = "Welcome to the HighTide!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      #flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  private

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

you may notice some code is commented out. I wasn't able to store in the database a user without an email (and for have a quick and dirty thing working now I comment the callback before_save, I also might add that I use the guidelines of Michael Hartl tut)

What happens is, when I run this code I get a `unknown attribute: password_confirmation error`, but when I comment out

```
  require 'bcrypt'
  attr_reader :password, :password_confirmation
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword::InstanceMethodsOnActivation
```

and use `has_secure_password instead`

I get a stack level too deep

I haven't figured out what to do

Comment: Based on Railscast you are using Devise.  What is the version you're using?

Comment: I'm not using Devise. User sign up & in is based on the rails tut

Comment: This error appears when you save the record as a guest or a User?

Comment: happens when I save as a User. He has no problem saving as a guest (unless I use the has_secure_passoword method)